# Incorrect solarized colorscheme in OSX Terminal.app

Tags: macos, vim, color-scheme

Here it is how my vim looks like:

file ~/.vimrc
[image]

and you can see that the color of line number is incorrect.
My terminal is set to be xterm-16color, and the TERM=xterm-16color, too.

I attempted to solve this problem in the following ways:

Solution 1:

add `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` into the .vimrc file and it looks the same.

and I also noted that I can use Solarized Light xterm-256color.terminal provided in the solarized git, but it looks ever worse.

using xterm-256color.terminal
[image]

Solution 2:

write the .vimrc file like this

```
set background=dark
" solarized options 
let g:solarized_visibility = "high"
let g:solarized_contrast = "high"
colorscheme solarized
```

it looks like the textcolor is correct(purple), but the background color is still grey.

Comment: See this question on Superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/311370/solarized-colors-in-vim-dont-seem-to-be-working-for-me